# Cannot unfollow locked post

Tags: bug, locked-posts, follow-posts

Some time ago I started following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389954/how-to-re-send-external-tester-invitations-on-apples-testflight-service); in the meanwhile, the post was deleted and then came back locked for "historical significance".

I do not wish to continue following it, but there does not seem to be an "Unfollow" option beneath it, as is the case with regular posts; in fact, the "Unfollow" option has gone away, along with the "Edit", "Close", and "Flag" ones - only "Share" remains'. And while it is understood that close/edit/flag actions are not applicable to locked posts, there should be an action for unfollowing.

Comment: @desertnaut Is it possible to unfollow it via the Followed posts profile tab? (I agree that it should be possible underneath the post itself as well, but it could be a workaround.)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349629/cannot-unfollow-locked-post-from-following-tab says it was fixed ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above, I realized that I can indeed unfollow the locked post from the Followed Posts profile tab, as described in the MSE thread [Cannot unfollow locked post from Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349629/cannot-unfollow-locked-post-from-following-tab) (but still *not* from the post itself, as claimed by the answer there).